# Sum, average and other

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert the integers from my list into the sum, and average of the list as well as state any temperatures below freezing F<32.
Whenever I try to get the sum or average I get error saying " unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' ". I am also aware that the (sum(list) is in the wrong place at the moment.

```
#Input
count = 0
list = []

while True:
    Temp = input("Enter a Temperature, enter q when done ")
    if Temp.lower() == 'q': 
      break
    list.append(Temp)
    count = count + 1
    print("List = ",list)
print("Number of Temperatures = ", count)
print("Highest Temperature = ",max(list))
print("Lowest Temperature = ",min(list))
print("Average Temperature= ",sum(list))
```

Comment: Fixed the issue with the averages. Still need to figure out how to list how many freezing temperatures there are.

Comment: You can find the count of freezing temps by doing: `print('number of freezing temps: ', len([x for x in lst if x <32]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
l= []

while True:
    Temp = input("Enter a Temperature, enter q when done ")
    if Temp.lower() == 'q': 
      break
    Temp = int(Temp)
    l.append(Temp)
    print("List = ",l)
print("Number of Temperatures = ", len(l))
print("Highest Temperature = ",max(l))
print("Lowest Temperature = ",min(l))
print("Average Temperature= ",sum(l)/len(l))
```

There are two changes:

1. You have to at some point convert them to `int`eger.
2. `sum` gives the `sum`, not the average, so you need the `sum` divided by the `len`gth.
3. Removed your `count`, as it isn't needed.
4. Changed `list` to `l`, as it is a default keyword.